# Generating an application key in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Has the `php artisan key:generate` command been removed in Laravel 4?

Running it returns;

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                             
There are no commands defined in the "key" namespace.
```

How should you generate keys now? Or do you need to create one manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time the question was asked, this feature had not yet been implemented for Laravel. It has now.

This is one of the dangers of asking questions about software that's not yet been released. The answers will change.

Comment: At the time the question was asked, Laravel 4 was pre-release, still under active development and this feature had not yet been implemented. So it was necessary, as this answer says, to generate the key manually. However, the feature has been implemented now, so the command attempted in the original questions will now work.