# Laravel 4 Artisan commands

Tags: php, command-line-interface, laravel, laravel-4

I am having some trouble using Laravel 4's artisan. When running a basic

```
php artisan key:generate
```

I get this error:

```
[InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "key" namespace
```

I've read in a few places and have updated composer with the command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

but this returns:

```
Nothing to install or update
```

and the problem still stands.

*Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.*

Comment: When did you download Laravel 4? a quick search turned this up
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231916/generating-an-application-key-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update composer itself first

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

then update you composer packages

```
php composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php - this is where the key:command is defined.

Then , look for vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/KeyGeneratorServiceProvider.php - this is where the command is registered to be used with artisan.

Most likely something is messed up in your installation

Answer (score 0):

Have you generated keys in `Laravel` 4 yet? The process is somewhat different from L3 in that you do not delete the 'Your key goes here!!!' text from this file.

```
app/config/app.php
```

You leave that text there and artisan writes over it.

You may already know this and be facing a different issue.